# I'm having trouble following these instructions: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/FAQ.html#ssi-part-i

Tags: apache, configuration, server-side-includes

I want my apache server to parse shtml files so I can include them in other html files, but I can't seem to understand how to modify the config files, even with these instructions: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/FAQ.html#ssi-part-i

Could anyone provide really really specific instructions? Such as specifically what files to open, and where and how to add certain instructions.

Comment: are you really running apache 1.3.x?

Comment: I think its Apache 2.0.63. I downloaded MAMP from here: http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the directory where your index.html file is (and I assume your shtml file(s) are) create a file named ".htaccess" and put these three lines in that file:

```
Options +Includes
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

Then test if server-side includes (SSI) are working.
(reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html#configuring )
You could also try the forums for the MAMP product you're using in case they've made any customizations to apache.